# Convert outdated stored class to updated class

Tags: java, class

I am facing a problem with the classes. I store data in Serializable classes as a Java Object, not as a series of variables at some places. However, when I make changes to the class in question, Java would immediately throw an Error.

For example this is an old class:

```
class Demo implements Serializable{
    private int a; private int b; int c;
    public void doSomething(){}
    public void doSomethingElse(){}
}
```

Which gets updated to:

```
class Demo implements Serializable{
    private int a; private private int b; private int c; private String x; private String y; private String z;
    public void doSomething(){}
    public void doSomethingElse(){}
    public void doAnotherThing(){}
    public void doYetAnotherThing(){}
}
```

Is there a way to convert the old Object to the new one seamlessly without having to name the new class as DemoNew or something and then transferring the values one by one?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the `serialVersionUID` is for. If you declare it in your new class, and it has the same value as it had when the object was serialized, then Java will know that the new class is still compatible with the old class, and will initialize a, b, and c (and will leave the other fields to their default value).

So, get the old serialVersionUID from the error being thrown, and add this field to the class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = ...;
```

Of course, that only works if the new class is effectively still compatible with the old one. If you renamed or removed fields, then you'll have to make it compatible by explicitely reading the object as it was at the time of serialization.

If I were you, I would stop using serialization as a long-term persistence mechanism. Choose an easily migratable format instead: a database, JSON, or XML for example.